# Using IEDriver with Ruby on Rails - How to navigate to start page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer-9, selenium-webdriver

I have several written automated tests in Ruby on Rails that run on Chrome using Chromedriver. I'd like to take those tests and start running them on IEdriver, but currently, when I start the tests, it opens in my local host and states that "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server"

I've read that this is normal, but given that the first steps of the test is to navigate to our company website, I'm not sure what I need to do to selenium or to my tests to help it navigate to a valid website to start.

Comment: All good, it was zoom settings.

Answer (score 0):

All good, it was zoom settings in the ie9 window.

Comment: Megan, can you please provide steps in how you fixed this error, as I'm having the same issue.